# PS3 Audio Output

Tags: ps3

I have a PS3 connected to a computer led monitor which has no sound output so I have an Logitech 2.1 audio system connected to that monitor. I want to connect the sound sytem to the PS3 but the cable of the sound system is probably for computer (only green audio and pink microphone cable). How can I connect it to the PS3 ? Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I imagine: http://www.cablewholesale.com/specs/35mm-to-rca/30s1-01400.htm

[image: IO audio ports]

Take the RCA audio output from the PS3 and convert it to the 3.5mm jack you need. The adapter will need to be female/female if I'm understanding your cabling correctly.

Comment: So the white and red RCA cables will be plugged to the back side of the connecter and the green audio cable will be connected to the front. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. You're combining the left and right channels of the RCA into one 3.5mm (headphone) stereo jack.